# How to stop event bubbling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have this code below and I would like to stop the click function to fire up when I click on the child div, but I can't get it work. What am I missing?

```
child.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is the [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/csongor_kocsis/pen/ozzKBX) where it should be used.

Comment: remove listener

Comment: Can you  @Infer-on edit the codepen so I can see what you meant?

Comment: @guradio I cannot click on the tabs. What I would like to achieve is be able to click on the tab but when I click on for example the child div -> nothing happens. Right now if you click on anywhere on the tab area it triggers it and closes/opens it.

Comment: stopPropagation should work as expected and stop the propagation of the event. The problem in your codepen is that you need to add the event listener to each of the children in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

child is a **collection of elements** (array)...
you have to loop trough it:

```
for(var i=0; i<child.length; i++){
  child[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation();}else{e.cancelBubble=true;}
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Using this you will avoid the dafault operation, for example open link when you click on `<a>`

**EDIT**

If you open the code pen and you add this code ath the end of JS:

```
 document.querySelector(".application-blurb").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert("You click");                                                                                 
 });
```

You will note that the OP target is achieved

Comment: OP wants to stop bubbling up not the default function

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
return false
```

to your code. It should work.

Comment: Can you help me out @JuicyScripter?